Selenium is not able to click on menu button on SEC.gov page
I'm trying to get an href link to download an XBRL file for a 10-Q financial report from an SEC webpage. Selenium is able to open the webpage but then it must click on the menu button in the top left to expand the menu to get to the 'Save XBRL Zip File' button but fails to do so. When I run my code, the TimeoutException is raised, no matter how much waiting time is specified. The XPATH is the one selected by the element selector when I inspect the html of the opened webpage. I am very new to programming. I found similar questions but the answers did not solve my issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!
This code is a subset of my script. Selenium worked fine up to this point including clicking other buttons. In the subet, below, if there are no issues, the webpage should open and the menu should be expanded. You can left click on the menu to see the expanded form. I tried adding logging and try and except statements to debug. I have also tried all other XPATHs that seem to point to the menu button. I tried expanding the menu button using javascript with <driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", menu_button)> Causes I can think of are: a text popup for the button appears when I hover over it and might be interfering with Selenium; javascript is interfering. Since I can see the href link for the XBRL file when I inspect the webpage opened by Selenium, I tried using Beautifulsoup to get the href to no avail.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# Initialize the Edge WebDriver (I have not tried Chrome because I was having issues with the 
# driver)
driver = webdriver.Edge()

# Open the webpage
url = r'https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204424000079/goog-20240630.htm'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to fully load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    # Get the menu element
    menu_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='menu-dropdown-link']/span[2]")))

    # Logging for debugging
    print(f"Menu button displayed: {menu_button.is_displayed()}")
    print(f"Menu button enabled: {menu_button.is_enabled()}")

    # Click on the menu to expand it
    menu_button.click()

# Print exceptions for debugging
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("Element not found: ", e)

except ElementNotInteractableException as e:
    print("Element not interactable: ", e)

except ElementClickInterceptedException as e:
    print("Element click intercepted: ", e)

except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
    print("Stale element reference: ", e)

except ElementNotVisibleException as e:
    print("Element not visible: ", e)

except TimeoutException as e:
    print("Timeout: ", e)

The output, which I can't understand and Copilot says is not very informative, is:
Timeout:  Message:
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF729758162+13538]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7296E1E19+595513]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7294FE6CF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF729542960]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF729542A1F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72957D627]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72956203F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF729538147]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72957B1EE]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF729561C63]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72953766E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72953683C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF729537221]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF729919704+1099860]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF72965D8FC+53532]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF729650E25+1605]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF729918695+1095653]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7296EC991+27777]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7296E6D14+4100]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7296E6E4B+4411]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7296DCFD0+575472]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF7C437374+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF7D3BCC91+33]


I answered my own question. Selenium was not able to access the menu button because it was in a different iframe. I added code to switch to the iframe, which contained the menu button, after Selenium initially opened the webpage, then my code was able to find and click the menu button. I then switched back to the default content so that the expanded menu was visible on the webpage.
The fixed code is:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# Initialize the Edge WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()

# Open the webpage
url = r'https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204424000079/goog-20240630.htm'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the specific '+' link to be present and clickable
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Swith to the iframe that contains the menu button
driver.switch_to.frame("ixvFrame")

try:
    menu_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "menu-dropdown-link")
    # menu_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main-navbar']/ul[1]/li/a[@class='nav-link dropdown-toggle click show']")))
    print(f"Menu button displayed: {menu_button.is_displayed()}")
    print(f"Menu button enabled: {menu_button.is_enabled()}")

    menu_button.click()

    # Switch back to the default content
    driver.switch_to.default_content()


except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("Element not found: ", e)

except ElementNotInteractableException as e:
    print("Element not interactable: ", e)

except ElementClickInterceptedException as e:
    print("Element click intercepted: ", e)

except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
    print("Stale element reference: ", e)

except ElementNotVisibleException as e:
    print("Element not visible: ", e)

except TimeoutException as e:
    print("Timeout: ", e)


You need first of all to click on the menu in order to render its options. After that you can navigate the menu itself.
Using the Chrome driver you could do this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    url = r'https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204424000079/goog-20240630.htm'
    driver.get(url)
    driver.switch_to.frame("ixvFrame")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "menu-dropdown-link"))).click()
        menu = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dropdown-menu")))
        for a in menu.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a"):
            if href := a.get_attribute("href"):
                print(a.text, href)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

Output:
Save XBRL Instance https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204424000079/goog-20240630_htm.xml
Save XBRL Zip File https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204424000079/0001652044-24-000079-xbrl.zip
Open as HTML https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204424000079/goog-20240630.htm


Thank you for your suggestion but I figured out the problem. It was that the menu button was contained within a different iframe.

@catman1 Yes. You may have noticed driver.switch_to.frame("ixvFrame") in my answer
